# declare variable scala as set of instructions

Tags: scala, f#, functional-programming

Is it possible to declare a variable in scala as the result of a series of instructions?. I'm trying to do something equivalent to the following F# snippet

```
let gSmall, gLarge, defaultOrder = 
    if g1remainingNodesToMap.Count <= g2remainingNodesToMap.Count then
        g1remainingNodesToMap, g2remainingNodesToMap, true
    else g2remainingNodesToMap, g1remainingNodesToMap, false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can do something like this in Scala:

```
val (gSmall, gLarge, defaultOrder) = 
if (g1remainingNodesToMap.size <= g2remainingNodesToMap.size) { 
    (g1remainingNodesToMap, g2remainingNodesToMap, true)
} else {
    (g2remainingNodesToMap, g1remainingNodesToMap, false)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent in Scala is the following:

```
val (gSmall, gLarge, defaultOrder) = 
  if (g1remainingNodesToMap.size <= g2remainingNodesToMap.size)
    (g1remainingNodesToMap, g2remainingNodesToMap, true)
  else (g2remainingNodesToMap, g1remainingNodesToMap, false)
```

Now you can reference `gSmall`, `gLarge`, and `defaultOrder`. To make this concrete:

```
scala> val g1remainingNodesToMap = Map("one" -> 1, "two" -> 2)
g1remainingNodesToMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(one -> 1, two -> 2)

scala> val g2remainingNodesToMap = Map("three" -> 3, "four" -> 4, "five" -> 5)
g2remainingNodesToMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(three -> 3, four -> 4, five -> 5)

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val (gSmall, gLarge, defaultOrder) = 
  if (g1remainingNodesToMap.size <= g2remainingNodesToMap.size)
    (g1remainingNodesToMap, g2remainingNodesToMap, true)
  else (g2remainingNodesToMap, g1remainingNodesToMap, false)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

gSmall: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(one -> 1, two -> 2)
gLarge: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(three -> 3, four -> 4, five -> 5)
defaultOrder: Boolean = true

scala> gSmall
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(one -> 1, two -> 2)

scala> gLarge
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(three -> 3, four -> 4, five -> 5)

scala> defaultOrder
res2: Boolean = true
```